# Como adicionar itens em um array corretamente?

Tags: php, html, array

Estou tentando criar arrays com dias da semana. "Aparentemente" parece funcionar:

```
$array_dia_da_semana = array("DOMINGO","SEGUNDA","TER&Ccedil;A","QUARTA","QUINTA","SEXTA","S&Aacute;BADO");

$array_dia_da_semana_d = [];
$array_dia_da_semana_s = [];
$array_dia             = [];

$data = new DateTime('2017-08-14');     // Pega a data de hoje
for ($a=1; $a <=7; $a++)
{   
    $array_dia[$a - 1] = $data;
    echo(date_format($array_dia[$a - 1],"Y-m-d") . "  iiii<br>");

    $diaN = date( "w", strtotime($data->format('Y-m-d')));
    echo("dia em numero.. " . $diaN) . "<br> ";
    $data->modify('+1 day');

    $array_dia_da_semana_s[] = $array_dia_da_semana[$diaN];
    echo($array_dia_da_semana_s[$a-1] . "<br>");        
    $array_dia_da_semana_d[] = $diaN;       
    echo($array_dia_da_semana_d[$a-1] . "<br>");    
}
```

Todos os `echos` me mostram corretamente o que eu quero ver. Contudo, se logo abaixo desse for fizer outro for:

```
for ($a=0; $a <=6; $a++)
{   
    echo(date_format($array_dia[$a],"Y-m-d") . "  <br>");
}
```

O que eu vejo é que todos os itens do array estão com a **mesma data**. Que nesse caso é o último dia manipulado "2017-08-21".

Realmente não sei o motivo desse comportamento.

Comment: O objetivo código é criar um calendario?

Comment: Boa tarde.. Estou fazendo uma tela de horarios.  Com os arrays montados cada ABA terá um select com o DIA da variavel-array $array_dia.  Então quando monto a primeira aba eu passo o parametro $array_dia[0] que teria que conter o dia 2017-08-14 a segunda aba passo o parametro $array_dia[1] que teria que conter o dia 2017-08-15 e assim por diante :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse comportamento é descrito no tópico [Objetos e Referências](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.references.php#language.oop5.references) da documentação do `PHP`, nele diz:

> A partir do PHP 5, uma variável objeto não contém mais o próprio
>   objeto como valor. Ela contém um identificador do objeto que permite
>   que os acessadores do objeto encontrem o objeto real.

Quando você faz a modificação no objeto, através do método abaixo:

```
$data->modify("+1 day");
```

Toda a referência para ele está sendo alterada também. Para evitar isso, você pode passar o valor para outra variável, ou já que está fazendo esse laço de repetição para os dias. Uma possível solução seria:

```
for ($a=1; $a <=7; $a++) {   
    $data = new DateTime('2017-08-14');     // Pega a data de hoje
    $array_dia[$a - 1] = $data;
    $diaN = date( "w", strtotime($data->format('Y-m-d')));
    $data->modify("+{$a} day");

    $array_dia_da_semana_s[] = $array_dia_da_semana[$diaN];
    $array_dia_da_semana_d[] = $diaN;       
}
```

Utilizando [`date`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php):

```
$data = date('Y-m-d');   
for ($a=1; $a <=7; $a++) {   

    $array_dia[$a - 1] = $data;
    $diaN = date( "w", strtotime($data));
    $data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$data} +1 day"));

    $array_dia_da_semana_s[] = $array_dia_da_semana[$diaN];
    $array_dia_da_semana_d[] = $diaN;       
}
```

Comment: Bom dia @Marcelo de Andrade... Obrigado pela atenção. De fato o problema era o OBJETO E REFERENCIA :)  Com sua ajuda consegui transpor mais este obstáculo. Obrigado e abraços :)

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza se alguma das respostas ajudou a resolver o problema, marque-a como resolvida. Caso tenha dúvidas sobre, dá uma lida em: [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia a todos
De fato o problema era o que o @Marcelo de Andrade falou : Objetos e referencia 
Meu voto vai para ele, contudo o que ele postou eu "ACHO" que esta com um pequeno erro de lógica. Se não converter a data para string ANTES de jogar para dentro do array, tudo continua sendo por referencia. Então acho que com o código abaixo tudo se resolve.

```
$array_dia_da_semana = array("DOMINGO","SEGUNDA","TERÇA","QUARTA","QUINTA","SEXTA","SÁBADO");

$array_dia_da_semana_d = [];
$array_dia_da_semana_s = [];
$array_dia             = [];

$data = new DateTime('2017-08-14');     // Pega a data de hoje
//$data =  new DateTime($_POST['pdata']);
for ($a=1; $a <=7; $a++)
{   
    $array_dia[] = date_format($data,"Y-m-d"); // Unica linha alterada. converter a data para string.
    //echo(date_format($array_dia[$a - 1],"Y-m-d") . "  iiii<br>");

    $diaN = date( "w", strtotime($data->format('Y-m-d')));
    //echo("dia em numero.. " . $diaN) . "<br> ";
    $data->modify('+1 day');



    $array_dia_da_semana_s[] = $array_dia_da_semana[$diaN];
    //echo($array_dia_da_semana_s[$a-1] . "<br>");      
    $array_dia_da_semana_d[] = $diaN;       
    //echo($array_dia_da_semana_d[$a-1] . "<br>");  
}


for ($a=0; $a <=6; $a++)
{   
    echo($array_dia[$a]."  <br>");
    echo($array_dia_da_semana_s[$a]."  <br>");
    echo($array_dia_da_semana_d[$a]."  <br>");
}
```

Só tenho a agradecer ao @Marcelo de Andrade por compartilhar seu conhecimento conosco :) Obrigado, e abraços a todos.:)